# css convert text

Tags: html, css

What is the CSS property that converts:

1. all text to caps; and
2. then to the original text itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> all text to caps

[`text-transform: uppercase;`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_text_text-transform.asp)

> then to the original text itself

The text is still in the original casing. Delete the `text-transform:` property to revert.

Comment: “Delete the property” – Or overwrite it with `text-transform: none;`

Answer (score 1):

Another variation that you might be interested in is:

```
font-variant: small-caps;
```

The small-caps value sets text in smaller size **all capitals**. This style is often used in legal documents and license agreements.

To remove it you could simply remove the style unless is inherited, is such case use:

```
font-variant: normal;
```